# assigning values to column in pandas data-frame based on if condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a column A, which has values Y and N. I want to assign 1 for Y and 0 of N, using the if condition in python. The following code throws an error:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
if df1[df1['A']=='Y']:
    df1['A']=1
else:
    df1['A']=0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `.apply` with `lambda`.

**Ex:**

```
df["A"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "Y" else 0)
```